# How to make this Digital Clock code work appropriately in Java?

Tags: java

I have been trying to complete this code for the past 2 hours but I keep hitting roadblocks that prevent me from going any further. The end result should go as follows: In one column, the sum should display, and in a separate column, the number of times the sum occurs should also be displayed. I have tried many different ways of getting this to work, but it ends up either giving me an error or displays the wrong result.
The basis of this code was to work out a program to display the sums of the hours and minutes of a clock that add to 12, and list out how many times the numbers added to 12. For example, 10:29, 1+2+9=12. From there, I now need to display every sum up to 23 on the clock, and display how many times the sums add up to any number between 1 and 23.

```
public class AidanMClock4{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int hour = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int totalcount = 0;
    System.out.println("Here is the list of times");
    for(int h=1; h<=2; h++){
      for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
        int leftSide = (i/10)+(i%10);
        for(int j=1; j<=59; j++){
          int rightSide = (j/10)+(j%10);
          int sum = leftSide+rightSide;
          if(sum ==2){
            totalcount++;
            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\t Number of Times: " + totalcount);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the output appears like so:

```
Here is the list of times
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 1
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 2
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 3
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 4
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 5
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 6
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 7
Sum: 2   Number of Times: 8
```

It needs to display something along the lines of this:

```
Sum:1    Number of Times: 0
Sum:2    Number of Times: 8
Sum:3    Number of Times: 20
```

and so on until 23.
Please help me out!!

Comment: An explanation of what you're actually trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: Start by changing your title... nearly every question on StackOverflow could have this title.

Comment: There, I fixed my title and added more details on what I am trying to accomplish. I hope this helps give you a better understanding.

Comment: You're still not really explaining what you are trying to do. Eg., you talk about a 'sum', but not what you're summing. Anyway, I made a guess in my answer what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to sum the hours and minutes of the clock, i=hours, and j=minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;

class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {   
     int h_digit_1 = 0;
     int h_digit_0 = 0;
     int m_digit_1 = 0;
     int m_digit_0 = 0;

     int sums[] = new int[24];
     for( int sum: sums )
         sum=0;

     int currentSum = 0;

     for( int h = 0 ; h < 12 ; h++ )
     {
         if( h < 10 )
         {
            h_digit_1 = 0;
            h_digit_0 = h;
         }
         else
         {
            h_digit_1 = 1;
            h_digit_0 = h%10;
         }

         for( int m = 0 ; m < 60 ; m++ )
         {
             if( m < 10 )
             {
                 m_digit_1 = 0;
                 m_digit_0 = m;
             }
             else
             {
                 m_digit_1 = m/10;
                 m_digit_0 = m - m_digit_1*10;       
             }

             currentSum = h_digit_1+h_digit_0+m_digit_1+m_digit_0;
             sums[currentSum]++;//since currentSum is always less than 24, its safe to use it as index!! also, sums[currentSum] represents count of occurrence of currentSum!!
         }
     }

     for( int i = 0 ; i<sums.length ; i++ )
     {
         System.out.println(i+" is the sum of hour and minute digits "+ sums[i]+ " number of times");
     }
  }    
}
```

Comment: I would like to only make it a 12 hour day, and just double the counter that adds the amount of times

Comment: 24 is not for 24hr!! its the size of the array used to hold count of all possible sums. 23 is the maximum possible sum at 9:59, all other sums are less than 23.

Comment: then how do I make it for a 12 hour day?

Comment: that's already for 12 hr day. don't you get it?? logic is straight forward, determine hour and minute digits , add them to get currentSum then increment the sums[currentSum] to get the count for currentSum!!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I should've explained that I didn't want it to be in military time. Thank you though.

Comment: sums[0] holds count for all the times 0 is the sum of digits, sums[1] holds count for all the times 1 is the sum of digits, sums[2] holds count for all the times 2 is the sum of digits and so on..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to loop over all the possible times in a day, using a 12h clock, then for each time, sum the separate digits, and then count how many times each sum occurs.

The appropriate data structure for achieving something like this is a hashmap. This should achieve what you're looking for (short of printing it in a nice way)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<Integer, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();
    for(int h=1; h<=2; h++){
        for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
            int leftSide = (i/10)+(i%10);
            for(int j=1; j<=59; j++){
                int rightSide = (j/10)+(j%10);
                int sum = leftSide+rightSide;
                sums.put(sum, sums.getOrDefault(sum, 0) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sums);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I could make this display like the example I used in my code? or is that that possible with Hashmap

Comment: Yes, use `keySet()` to get all keys, then put this in a list and sort it. Then iterate the list and query the map on each iteration. On the other hand, maybe a simple array would be a better fit for your usecase, then you won't have to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with your code. I assume you are trying to loop over all the possible combinations of hours-minutes in a day and count when how many times the sum of the digits of each combination is equal to the values 1 to 23.

`for(int h=1; h<=2; h++)`
You don't appear to use h in your code, which means that all this does is make your code run twice.

```
for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
        int leftSide = (i/10)+(i%10);
        for(int j=1; j<=59; j++){
          int rightSide = (j/10)+(j%10);
          int sum = leftSide+rightSide;
```

For each iteration of the inner loop, `sum` will be the sum of the digits of `i` and `j`. I assume this is what you were trying to achieve.

```
if(sum ==2){
            totalcount++;
            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\t Number of Times: " + totalcount);
```

Whenever `sum` is equal to 2. You increase `totalcount` and print it.

If you mean to iterate over all possible sums from 1 to 23 and print the total amount of times the sum of the digits of `i` and `j` are equal to that number consider implementing the following changes.

**1) Change the outer loop(`h`) to iterate over the possible sum value.** This can be done by changing the loop to `for(int current_sum =1;current_sum<=23;current_sum++)`.

**2) Reset your counter for each iteration of said loop.** This can be done by having the line following the loop outlined in 1 be `int totalcount = 0;`

**3) Change the conditional to be if the sum of letters is equal to the current sum instead of 2.**

**4) Only print the total amount of sums once per iteration of the outer loop.** Take great care of the brackets and make sure your print line is the last line of the outer loop.

**5) Double the result instead of counting twice.** If you wish to count both for AM and PM, just print out `totalcount*2` instead of `totalcount`

EDIT:
If you followed #2, the variable that counts the amount of times a sum was equal to `current_sum` is `totalcount`. It should look something like this:

```
int sum = leftSide+rightSide;
if (sum == current_sum){
    totalcount++;
}
```

and at the outermost bracket:

```
 System.out.println("Sum: " + current_sum + "\t Number of Times: " + totalcount);
```

EDIT: Count your brackets carefuly, just before the end of the scope of the first for loop is where you should put your print statement.

```
 for(int current_sum=1; current_sum<=23; h++){
      for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
        int leftSide = (i/10)+(i%10);
        for(int j=1; j<=59; j++){
          //Here is the body that counts the sums. More code goes here.
          if(current_sum == sum){
          totalcount++;
          }//if bracked
        }//Ending of the innermost loop
      }//brackets that middle loop(i)
     System.out.println("Sum: " + current_sum + "\t Number of Times: " + 
     totalcount);
    }//brackets that close the outer loop (current_sum)
```

Comment: When I try to follow number 4, I get an error that says: cannot find variable sum.

Comment: Edited my post for with your answer for formatting reasons.

Comment: So do I put the print statement after the end bracket of the If statement? Or do I put in after the main public static void statement

Comment: You put it as the last statement of the outermost for loop. I've edited my reply with the relevent information